# Does it make sense to translate a submanifold in a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Given some manifold $M$ which is also equipped with some metric, for example Riemannian metric, let  $$S^r(x_0)=\{x\in M| d(x_0,x)=r\},$$ where $x_0\in M$ and $d$ is the distance. Now given another point $p\in M$,

> Does it make sense to talk about the **submanifold $S=S^r(x_0)+p$**?

Can I say that $S$ is  a translation of $S^r(x_0)$ by $p$?

Comment: What does it mean $+$  for the manifold?Does it have an algebra structure?

Comment: dmtri Not really

Comment: Without more context, if one picks a vector field $X \in \Gamma(TM)$, then provided its flow $\theta_t$ is defined on some $(-\epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)$, $\epsilon > 0$, (which is always the case when $M$ is compact, for example) then we can ask about the image of $S$ under the flow $\theta_1$, which is something like translation along $X$. This generalizes translation of a submanifold of a real or complex vector space $V$, where we take our vector field to be the one where (at each $x$) $X_x$ is the vector identified with $p \in V$ under the canonical isomorphism $T_x V \cong V$.

Comment: (But NB such a flow will not respect the metric structure, that is, will not preserve distances in $M$. This occurs precisely when $X$ is a Killing field of the Riemannian metric, but for a typical manifold the only Killing field is the zero vector field.)

Comment: @Travis! You mean when in a Riemannian space $W$ is a Killing vector field then I can talk about the translation of a submanifold $S$ by the flow of $W$?
And in this case the distance is preserved?

Comment: Majid, I wouldn't use the term "translation" in that context without more explanation, but yes, (by definition) flowing along a Killing field preserves distances. At least for $t$ for which they are globally defined, which includes the case when $M$ is compact, the flow maps $\theta_t$ of a Killing field are isometries $(M, g) \to (M, g)$. But this situation is a subset of the situation that John Hughes describes in his answer, where one has an isometry $(M, g) \to (M, g)$. Reversing the picture, Killing fields are, informally, infinitesimal isometries.

Comment: Travis. Thanks. Where can I read about this matter more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no. For instance, consider what happens if you take the unit sphere (call it the earth), and translate the equator "by the north pole"? If you add a point on the equator to the north pole (in 3-space, where addition makes sense) you get a circle...floating in the tangent plane to the north pole, i.e., not even a subset of $S^2$.

There *are* some notions of translation in some manifolds, particularly ones with an ample supply of self-isometries (e.g., the torus), but ... they're not based strictly on "addition," which may not even be well-defined.